# Bootstrap tooltip with absolute position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm having strange issue when having absolutely positioned element with Bootstrap tooltip.

Tooltip is not rendered correctly according to parent element, please see fiddle:    `[http://jsfiddle.net/QsYPv/152/][1]`

When parent element is not positioned absolutely everything is working just fine. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

*Note: I can't set CSS with of absolutely positioned element?*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

this should fix it

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
   container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Sweeet @godmode works like charm. I owe you beer six pack :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the element with position:absolute has some positive z-index if it's supposed to lay overtop of another element:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="some tooltip">
        <span>absolute-flow</span>
    </div>
    <span>inline-flow</span>
</div>
```

Comment: My elements had the same undefined z-index. This did not cause problems with the absolute-ly positioned element showing, but the tooltip would not show on hover. Making the z-index some positive value allowed the tooltip to pop.