# Why are my bootstrap tooltips not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bevor i use a plugin for Bootstrap i always test it before. This is why my html is so simple.
It would be great if you could help me out with my tooltips.

Ps: i am really new to coding Websites

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap-Basis-Vorlage</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip links">Tooltip links</button>

<script>
$(function () {
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include latest `jquery` version

Comment: It is working https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/91/

Comment: i don't get it. This is making me like really mad

Comment: You use jQuery on document ready to call your code, but you do it before jQuery is loaded. Therefore it won't execute. Put jQuery script first, then your custom code after. Where you want to put your bootstrap script(before/after custom code) is optional.

Comment: i still get the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap-Basis-Vorlage</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip links">Tooltip links</button>




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

my first attempt to resolve bootstrap tooltip issues is to change the selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});
```

it's also possible that the tooltip is working, but isn't placed in front of your div

```
.tooltip({ container: 'body' })
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811884/3511012

Answer (score 1):

> Why are my bootstrap tooltips not working?

Because you initialize the jquery and bootstrap scripts after the code where you try to initialize the tooltip via jQuery. Swap them around. Scripts first, then your custom code.